# Django -- 'data' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

Im practicing data's CRUDS,and meet some error when I trying to code delete function.

in timesheet.html:

```
 {% for data in TR %}
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{data.month}}</th>
                        <th>{{data.worktime}}</th>
                        <th>{{data.email}}</th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><a href="{% url 'data:delete' data.0 %}"><button type="button">刪除</button></a></th>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

in views.py:

```
def delete(request, id):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sqldelete = """
                        delete from timesheet where idtimesheet = %s
                """
                cursor.execute(sqldelete, (id,))
        return redirect("/timesheet")
```

in urls.py

```
  urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.timesheet, name='timesheet'),
    # path('index/', views.index, name='index')
    path('data_db/', views.data_db, name='data_db'),

    path('delete/<int:idtimesheet>', views.delete, name="delete")
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:
`url 'data:delete'`

The problem is that Django doesn't recognise that first 'data' - is it the name of your app, or a namespace defined in your project-level urls.py when you `include()` the app urls.py?

if your urls.py that you've quoted is included in a higher-level urls.py, you should be able to namespace it by giving include a tuple locating the module containing the url_patterns list, and a namespace string. My full entry from the polls tutorial:

```
re_path(r'^polls/', include(('polls.urls', 'polls'))),
```

If you haven't got a namespace, then you don't need `data:`, just make it `url delete`

Comment: Good to hear. Could you 'accept' this answer when you get a chance? It's part of the reward mechanism here on StackOverflow.